# How to paint another object when the first one is offscreen?

Tags: java, paint

I need to make a system where a obstacle is drawn on the screen, when it scrolls off the screen, another one will be drawn at a random value (up to a max of a certain value) on the screen after that one.

I have some code here:

```
public int xElapsed = 0;
```

this is just incremented all the time, it is how much the player has moved.

```
obstacleHole.paint(g);

        if(obstacleHole.getX() <= 0){
            obstacleHole.paint(g);
        }
```

This is the paint function. The first obstacle is painted straight away, and the second after that condition is met. This is not working as intended, however.

```
x = position.nextInt(500 + player.xElapsed * 2);
```

and this is how the x coordinate of the obstacle is set. "position" is a random value generator.

This code is not working because only one obstacle ever shows up. How can I fix this to work as intended? I can provide extra code if necessary.

Here is the ObstacleHole class:

```
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Random;

public class ObstacleHole {

Player player = new Player();
Random position = new Random();

int x;
int y;
int dx = 1;
int width = 100;
int height = 100;

public ObstacleHole(){
    x = position.nextInt(500 + player.xElapsed * 2);
    y = 250;
}

public void move(){
    x = x - player.playerSpeed;
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
}

public Rectangle bounds(){
    return (new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}
}
```

Screen.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

  public class Screen extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

Player player = new Player();
ObstacleHole obstacleHole = new ObstacleHole();

public Screen(){
    addKeyListener(this);
    setDoubleBuffered(true);
    setFocusable(true);
    Timer tick = new Timer(5, this);
    tick.start();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint();
    player.move();
    obstacleHole.move();
    System.out.println(player.getXElapsed());
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
        player.paint(g);
        obstacleHole.paint(g);

        if(obstacleHole.getX() <= 0){
            obstacleHole.paint(g);
        }
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(player.jumpReady){
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            player.dy = -1;
            player.jumpReady = false;
        }
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}


 }
```

Player.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Player {

int x;
int y;
int dx;
public int xElapsed = 0;
public int dy;
int width = 64;
int height = 64;
public int playerSpeed = 3;
public boolean isMoving = true;
public boolean hasJumped = false;
public boolean jumpReady = true;

public Player(){
    x = 150;
    y = 250;
}

public void move(){
    x = x + dx;
    y = y + dy;

    xElapsed++;

    if(hasJumped == true){
        dy = -1;
    }

    if(y == 150){
        dy = 1;
    }   

    if(y == 250){
        dy = 0;
        jumpReady = true;
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
}

public int getX(){
    return x;
}

public int getY(){
    return y;
}

public int getXElapsed(){
    return xElapsed;
}
}
```

Comment: more code please :D, and a screen shot would help better of course

Comment: To be honest, there is not much more I can add as this is pretty much all the relevant code, what would you like to see specifically? Maybe then I could provide something that is relevant.

Comment: We would probably need to see enough code so that we can understand the problem. Better if it compiles, best if it is very small, compiles, runs, and shows us the problem.

Comment: your explanation is a little hard to understand (at least for me), a visual diagram (maybe a screen shot with comments) would help to much, thanks

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener. See [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for the reasons why and a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you are painting *obstacleHole*, then when the x value of *obstacleHole* is less than or equal to 0, you draw it again. All you are doing is sending two calls to the paint() method of the same object.

If you want to paint a second one, you will need to create another object. Or, alternatively, move the original object back onto the screen after it leaves.

It is hard to give you sample code when you have provided so little context, but try something like this:

```
MyObject obstacleHoleA = new MyObject();
MyObject obstacleHoleB = new MyObject();

obstacleHoleA.paint(g);

if(obstacleHoleA.getX() <= 0){
    obstacleHoleB.paint(g);
}
```

Or this:

```
obstacleHole.paint(g);

if(obstacleHole.getX() <= 0){
    obstacleHole.setX(randomValueUpToAMaxOfCertainValue);
}
```

Edit: There are a lot of things I would do a lot differently with the above code, but they are outside the scope of the question.

Try this for your ObstacleHole class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Random;

public class ObstacleHole {

Player player = new Player();
Random position = new Random();

int x;
int y;
int dx = 1;
int width = 100;
int height = 100;

public ObstacleHole(){
    x = getNewPosition();
    y = 250;
}

public void move(){
    x = x - player.playerSpeed;

    if(x < 0 - width) {
        x = getNewPosition();
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
}

public Rectangle bounds(){
    return (new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

private int getNewPosition() {
    return 200 + position.nextInt(300);
}
}
```

Note the change to the constructor and move() method, along with the new method getNewPosition().

Comment: Thanks for helping! See my updated answer for some more code.